# Asp.Net code blocks not executed

Tags: asp.net

I have the below code in my ascx file.
The enclosing `<tr>` has `runat="server"`.

```
<td id="loading" style='<%= ShowLoadingImage("PageLoad") %>'></td>
```

This code is rendered to HTML without being executed, i.e. I see the same text on the html.
Whats the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `<%..%>` inside a control that has `runat=server` or in a control that is nested with some other control having `runat=server`.

I would suggest, make `<td id="loading" runat="server"...` and in server side code assign style like 
`loading.Attributes.Add("style", ShowLoadingImage("PageLoad"));`

Comment: Yes, that is what I did as a work around. But being able to do it on ascx file would be cleaner.

Comment: @NullHead, i think you have to do it this way.